# Is "insomatic" a word? Is it used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> "I'm not planning to sleep," Mary said. She revealed her **insomatic**
>   scheme to John.

(Meaning Mary revealed her plan to stay up late the whole night to John).

Is this usage correct? If not, what's a better alternative?

Comment: Are you trying to make or find a word related to "insomnia"? I think you left out the "n". You can see common adjectives starting with "insomn-" at [Onelook Dictionary Search](https://www.onelook.com/?w=insomn*&posfilter=a); the only one is "insomniac".

Comment: Even if _insomatic_ were a word (it’s not; as sumelic points out, it’s _insomniac_), the word is not correctly used. [Insomnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insomnia) is an actual disorder, and a debilitating one at that. It is an **inability** to sleep. Planning to stay up all night is not insomnia.

Comment: [*Somatic* does exist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/somatic) but I don't know what *insomatic* would mean.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. // 'Mary revealed to John her plan to stay up all night.'

Comment: @Janus I was about to say that there is a broader sense, but I find that only one of the dictionaries I've checked in doesn't require the medical condition. I believe that usage has changed markedly since I first met the term. I'll ask my old friend Rip.

Comment: @Edwin Even in the broader sense (which I do agree exists) that doesn’t require the actual medical condition, insomnia is still firmly an _inability_ to sleep to me. Lots of people would call it insomnia if they can’t fall asleep one night—but going out to a party and staying out all night long wouldn’t count as insomnia with anyone I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have said, "insomatic" is not currently a word, but that itself shouldn't stop you using it - neologisms are fine as long as their meaning is (fairly) obvious.

However, the guessed meaning of "insomatic" (for most people) would be "not of the body", since "somatic" means "of the body" (usually meaning "as opposed to the mind") - for example *"His blindness isn't somatic - it must be due to a cognitive disorder"*.  The prefix **in-** usually denotes a removal or lack of something, eg *involuntary* vs *voluntary*.

If you're going to invent a neologism meaning "involving insomnia, or a lack of sleep", which I take to be the intended meaning in your sentence, then it should involve a transformation to "insomnia" - perhaps "**insomniatic**"?  I think most people who guessed the meaning would get it right.  Technically, insomnia is an inability to sleep, rather than a conscious choice, but I think that would be allowed under a "poetic licence", which one assumes to be applied to all neologisms.

Comment: Most people _wouldn't_ guess that 'insomatic' might be intended to mean 'not of the body'. At least, most of the ones I've met. ELU is about _usage_, not the English of 2130 (perhaps).

Comment: @Edwin: Max's interpretation certainly crossed my mind! Admittedly I might have been influenced by the fact that I'd noticed my daughter reading *Brave New World* earlier today, which put me in mind of ***soma***. But I'd also say that dropping the ***n*** from ***insomnia*** and derivatives seems a bit of a stretch to me.

Comment: @FF I think many of the people I've met would think of a type of camera. Mind you, many wouldn't know how 'somatic' is used. I don't meet many linguists. I've asked my wife (BA; French subsidiary) what she thinks 'insomatic' might mean, and she didn't come up with anything like 'not of the body'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth perhaps "most" was an exaggeration, but we shouldn't make any conclusions based on a one-person survey either.

Comment: I took the precaution of limiting my largely unsupported statement to a 'comment'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth touché

Answer (score 1):

Insomniatic is not found in dictionaries, but is seen used:[image: poem]

From Sgriobhaiche by Chris Boyd

> Sorry, not really an answer, but I think it is interesting anyway.